# Unable to successfully get a return from a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return-value

I'm trying to return a value (spoken audio is successfully transcribed) from the following function:

```
def takeCommand():
    model = Model("model")
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=8000)
    stream.start_stream()

    while True:
        data = stream.read(4000, exception_on_overflow=False)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            x=json.loads(rec.Result())
            print(x["text"])
            statement = print(x["text"])
            return statement
            
        else:
            #print(rec.PartialResult())
            pass
    
    #print(rec.FinalResult())
```

I can successfully see the text being transcribed through

> print(x["text"])

However, return is giving me a NoneType error, as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jarvis_vosk.py", line 116, in <module>
    if "thank you" in statement or "ok bye" in statement or "stop" in statement:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

So the function takeCommand() is empty and I can't understand why the return value isn't being passed on?

Your assistance it greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it... i just needed to change

> statement = print(x["text"])

to take account of the statement being a string.... and not just printing it:

> statement = str(x["text"])

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
statement = print(x["text"])
return statement
```

You can try this :)

```
statement = x["text"]
return statement
```

Or just

```
return x["text"]
```